# SQL Check if a value is close to any value in a different table

Tags: sql

Having a problem with a sql question.  Here are the two tables:

```
ID   |   Timestamp
1    |   143
2    |   429

Timestamps_master
150
322
539
```

The question I want to ask is: how many IDs in the first table have a timestamp that's within 10 seconds of a timestamp in timestamps_master. So in the above set-up, it should be 1.

Outside sql, I'd just do some loops, but can't figure out what the sql equivalent would be.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: what sql server are you using?

Comment: It's actually my company's internal version of sql, similar to sql 2011 standard but not exactly... if you have an idea for a solution, I can look at how to do it with our specific dialect.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (ANSI SQL's timestamps is way different.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Id from tablename where(diff(Timestamps_master,Timestamp)<=10)or (diff(Timestamps_master,Timestamp)>=-10);
```

Comment: Just curious, which dbms is this for?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.timestamp 
FROM t1, t2 
WHERE t1.timestamp BETWEEN t2.time-10 and t2.time+10
```